# CentOS 8 - lightDM installation

Tags: centos, dnf, lightdm

I am unable to install the lightDM display manager in CentOS 8. When trying to use the command

```
$sudo dnf install lightdm
```

I get the error

> Problem: conflicting requests
>     nothing provides lightdm-greeter = 1.2 needed by lightdm-1.30.0-3.el8.x86_64
>   (try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)

Am I missing anything? Like adding a repo for lightm in via dnf?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you try `--skipbroken` or `--nobest` as was suggested?

Comment: @DavidPostill, Yes i have tried with those two options, using `--skipbroken` the dependencies get resolved and the commands ends with `Nothing to do, Complete!` and using `--nobest` the same error which i mentioned in the question occurs.